# person is undefined. Works with msg.guild, but not with client.guilds.cache.get("valid id")

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
var mainServer = client.guilds.cache.get("a valid id")
var person = mainServer.members.cache.get(obj.users[userIndex].discordid)
```

mainServer is defined and is the correct server, but person is undefined. The user id is also valid. Any ideas why discord.js can't get me the user?

Comment: And what is `userIndex` and `obj.users[userIndex].discordid`? Have you checked their value?

Comment: Yes they are both valid.

Comment: I'm not sure why msg.guild works but `mainServer.members.fetch(obj.users[userIndex].discordid)` would be more appropriate unless you are sure that the user is already in the cache (`mainServer.members.cache`).

Comment: I'd have to remake the code to work with promises. How do users even get in the cache anyways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The person you're trying to get might be uncached, try fetching them with `guild.members.fetch(<id here>)`